# Does reciting Navagraha Stotram change the effect of planets?

Tags: astrology, stotra, vyasa, navagraha

There is a [NavaGraha stotram](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/navanew.html) composed by Rishi Vedavyasa.

These are the benefits of reciting this stotram.

> इति व्यासमुखोद्गीतं यः पठेत्सुसमाहितः । दिवा वा यदि वा रात्रौ
> विघ्नशान्तिर्भविष्यति ॥ १०॥
>
> Those who read the song sung by VyAsa, will be joyous, sovereign and
> powerful, and will succeed in appeasing obstacles, occurring by day or
> by night .
>
> नरनारीनृपाणां च भवेद्दुःस्वप्ननाशनम् । ऐश्वर्यमतुलं
> तेषामारोग्यं पुष्टिवर्धनम् ॥
>
> Bad dreams of men, women and kings alike will be destroyed and they
> will be endowed with unparalleled riches, good health and enhancing
> nourishment.

> ग्रहनक्षत्रजाः पीडास्तस्कराग्निसमुद्भवाः । ताः सर्वाः
> प्रशमं यान्ति व्यासो ब्रूते न संशयः ॥
>
> All the pain, devastation caused by fire, planets and stars will be
> of the past, so spoke VyAsa, emphatically.

But we know about Karaka planets and Maraka planets in Astrology.
So, does this stotra increase the planet's influence or decrease it's influence in the native's life.

I'm asking this as let's say someone's sun is maraka and he is advised to reduce sun's effect by doing Donations etc. So, reciting this stotra will increase sun's influence or decrease it?

Similarly, let's say Saturn is beneficial for the native, so reciting this stotra will increase Saturn's influence or decrease it?

**Can anyone recite it regardless the planetary positions in the birth chart?**
**Please correct me if I'm missing something here.**

Comment: If you recite the Stotra the planets which are benefic for your chart will do even more good but the planets which are malefic (maraka) for you will gradually stop giving bad results .. so everyone can recite it irrespective any other considerations.

Comment: Another Stotra which have similar benefits is from Purana, Navagraha Pida Hara Stotram -- https://stotranidhi.com/en/navagraha-peedahara-stotram-in-english/

Comment: @Rickross OMG!!!   This is exactly what I thought and also told to others. But I did not get anything to back up my claim. So can u tell me what should I say to others if they ask me for some reason or anything.

Comment: @Rickross By the way, are you sure about that reason and also that it's safe to chant?

Comment: Reading Stotras increase positivity .. it is impossible to think that the act results in reduction of positivity ... One reads Stotras to increase positivity and reducing negativity (of the planets in this case). I also don't have a concrete source to prove this claim but I think that this is taken for granted and not a matter of debate.

Comment: @Rickross Thank you for telling 